# Change Assert behavior as per different parameters in Parameterized Junit test cases

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Is it possible to change the assert behavior as per the parameters of the @Parameters method.

```
Class abcTest
{
  ..
  @Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> testParameters()
  {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        {1},{2} 
        });
  }

  ..
  @Test
  public void test()
  {
    ...
    if(num == 1) { assertTrue(..); }
    if(num == 2) { assertFalse(..); }
    ...
  }
}
```

is it possible to define the assert behavior exactly the way we define parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest case you can pass expected values as parameters and use them in assertions, as shown in [javadoc](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html).

In more complex cases you need to encapsulate assert logic into objects and pass them as parameters.

If you need different assertions for the same values you can use `assertThat()` and `Matcher<T>`:

```
class abcTest
{
  @Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> testParameters()
  {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            {1, CoreMatchers.is(true)},
            {2, CoreMatchers.is(false)} 
        });
  }

  ..
  @Test
  public void test()
  {
      ...
      assertThat(value, matcher);
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if different parameters need completely different assertions you can pass them as `Runnable`s.

However, it may be not a good idea to use parameterized tests in this case - if you need completely different assertions for different cases it can be more elegant to create separate test methods for these cases, extracting their commons parts into helper methods:

```
@Test
public void shouldHandleCase1() {
   handleCase(1);
   assertTrue(...);
}

@Test
public void shouldHandleCase2() {
   handleCase(2);
   assertFalse(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this should help.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. It worked very well for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

recently I started [zohhak](https://github.com/piotrturski/zohhak) project. it let's you write

```java
@TestWith({
    "1, true",
    "2, false"
})
public void test(int value, boolean expectedResult) {
  assertThat(...).isEqualTo(expectedResult);
}
```